# Difference between list(dict) and dict.keys()?

Tags: python

Say I have a dict:

```
foo = {'a': 1}
```

Both `list(foo)` and `foo.keys()` return the same thing. What's the difference between the two?

Comment: In python3, `foo.keys()` returns a `view`

Comment: Note that `list()` call will basically iterate over the returned object from `__iter__`, so in case you override `dict`'s `__iter__` in a class and then call `.keys()` and `list()` on it then only the `list()` call will run the new `__iter__`.

Answer (score 27):

One difference is in Python 3. `foo.keys()` returns an iterator of the keys, which is what `foo.iterkeys()` does in Python 2, while `list(foo)` returns a list of the keys.

As noted below, `foo.keys()` doesn't exactly return an iterator in Python 3. It returns a `dict_keys` object (or view) which, among its operations, allows iteration. You can also do fun things such as set operations and multiple iteration. It still has the concept of lazy evaluation which makes iterators so powerful.

Comment: In Python 2, `list(foo)` essentially calls `foo.iterkeys()` and creates a list from its contents, insomuch as `foo.iterkeys()` and `iter(foo)` return the same object.

Comment: Yes , Check documentation as well - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html - The last point in footnotes. `dict.keys()` returns a dictionary view object (not iterator).

Answer (score 10):

Python3:

from the official [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

> Calling foo.keys() will return a dictionary view object. It supports
>   operations like membership test and iteration, but its contents are
>   not independent of the original dictionary – it is only a view.

in fact,

```
type(foo.keys())
```

gives

```
<class 'dict_keys'>
```

whereas in Python 2 both

```
type(list(foo))
type(foo.keys())
```

give

```
<type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 7):

There's no real difference in python 2, which is why I suspect `dict.keys` changed to return a view in python3 and `dict.viewkeys` was removed.

In python 3:

```
In [3]: foo = dict((k,k) for k in range(4))

In [4]: foo
Out[4]: {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}

In [5]: foo.keys?
Type:        builtin_function_or_method
String form: <built-in method keys of dict object at 0x7f45d8667708>
Docstring:   D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys

In [6]: foo.keys()
Out[6]: dict_keys([0, 1, 2, 3])

In [7]: type(foo.keys())
Out[7]: dict_keys

In [8]: for i in foo.keys():
   ...:     del foo[i]
   ...:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-659d5446ab29> in <module>()
----> 1 for i in foo.keys():
      2     del foo[i]
      3 

RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration

In [9]: for i in list(foo):
    del foo[i]

In [10]: foo
Out[10]: {}
```

The last two things are basically the thing you need to know about the difference between `dict.keys` and `list(dictionary)` in python**3**. `dict.keys` is *just* a view of the keys, so checking `item in dictionary.keys()` is O(1), but you can't iterate over `dictionary.keys()` and modify the dictionary at the same time.

They are both iterators, in that they both implement `__iter__`.

Comment: `list(foo)` gives you an entire new list object, right? That is why you can remove items from it, me thinks :)

Comment: Yeah, which is why you can iterate over that and delete from the dictionary.

Comment: What is the `foo.keys?` notation? It doesn't seem to work here for me.

Comment: It's [ipython](http://ipython.org/) magic, see the fourth bullet point here: http://pages.physics.cornell.edu/~myers/teaching/ComputationalMethods/python/ipython.html . It's basically equivalent to calling `help(foo.keys)`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, the `dict_keys` object returned by `.keys()` is just pointing to the actual dictionary keys (and changes when the dictionary is changed), while the `list` command creates a copy of the keys.
Therefore, the `dict_keys` is more lightweight and faster. The `list` should be used when modifying the dictionary while iterating over its keys. A slightly nonsensical example with dictionary `foo`:

```
>>> for kw in foo.keys():
...   foo.pop(kw)
```

leads to `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`, while the following works:

```
>>> for kw in list(foo):
...   foo.pop(kw)
```

Answer (score 0):

````
      'duration': [120.0, 240.0, 90.0, 16.0, 48.0],
      'rate': [0.11, 0.06, 0.08, 0.14, 0.07],
      'down_payment': [100000.0, 0.0, 8900.0, 0.0, 4300.0]} ```

data.keys()

dict_keys(['amount', 'duration', 'rate', 'down_payment'])

dict.keys produce a dictkeys. that we can only read . not can do change
````