# Difference between iterate dictionary.items() vs list(dictionary.items())

Tags: python

What is the difference between (the goal is to extract the k,v value)

```
for k,v in example_dict.items():
    print(k,v)
    do_something
```

vs

```
for k,v in list(example_dict.items()):
    print(k,v)
    do_something
```

The results look same

Comment: The second one creates a new list (which seems completely unnecessary)

Comment: Related: [Difference between list(dict) and dict.keys()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31837161/7851470).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the `list` is unnecessary in most cases, and might even be harmful.

The `.items()` method returns a "view" into the data. As per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> The objects returned by `dict.keys()`, `dict.values()` and `dict.items()` are view objects. They provide a dynamic view on the dictionary’s entries, which means that when the dictionary changes, the view reflects these changes.

This is *not the case* when you wrap it in `list`, which preserves the keys/values/items as they appeared when the list was created.

In general, you should not use the version with `list()` if you are iterating with `for`. It's superfluous at best and adds unnecessary visual clutter to the code.

Edit: As per [the other answer by Jan Stránský](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63706955/2954547), `list()` also performs a full iteration pass on the data in order to construct the list. This is quite wasteful!

Comment: Also takes more memory

Comment: @roganjosh as far as I understand (in CPython) the new list would consist of copies of all the pointers to the underlying data, and the data itself shouldn't be copied. So unless the list is really big, the memory increase is minor. However it will hold onto references of objects that have otherwise fallen out of scope, so it could in theory lead to memory leaks. But this is esoterica and not relevant to most Python programs (IMO).

Comment: Oh, I wasn't considering that much detail (though it probably is relevant to views), but more along the lines of why python 2 introduced `xrange`; it's better to have the generator. Sure, the memory footprint would be minor for smaller dicts, there's really no need to make a program more memory-hungry than it needs to be

Answer (score 2):

The difference is, well, obviously, the use of `list`.

The first approach is preferable, because [example_dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) [returns a dict view](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views) and `for k,v in example_dict.items():` iterates "directly" over the items.

With `for k,v in list(example_dict.items()):` you actually do **2** iterations. First the program do one loop to convert items to list. Then you do a second loop to iterate the list. So it is unnecessary.

Comment: Very good point that using `list` actually does an extra iteration pass!

Answer (score 2):

The difference here is the data type. You will not see it when iterating, but you will see it when printing normally:

```
d = {1: "first", 2: "second", 3: "third"}
d.items()
dict_items([(1, 'first'), (2, 'second'), (3, 'third')])
list(d.items())
[(1, 'first'), (2, 'second'), (3, 'third')]
```

at the last one I put the dict object (with the items() method) into a list and output it

Answer (score 1):

By definition, an `iterable` is any Python object capable of returning its members one at a time, permitting it to be iterated over in a `for`-loop.

A `list` is an `iterable`, however the method `dict.items()` already returns returns a `list` or a view of the dictionary's entries depending on the version of the language used.

`Python2`
If you call `list()` on a `list`, such as the one produced from `dict.items()` then a shallow copy is returned, meaning you will make a new `list` by the elements of the innermost list.
As mentioned in [What does the list() function do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581397/what-does-the-list-function-do-in-python)

`Python3`
As mentioned in https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views
The objects returned by `dict.items()` are view objects, and when they are used as an `iterable` they work the same, e.g when calling `list()`.

In either case, the `list()` call is redundant at best, and should be avoided.